# Force Channel API to poll

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

Hopefully Moishe sees this:  in development mode, the channel api client (javascript) resorts to polling... and uses a very fast polling rate.  After poking around I found that if I set

```
goog.appengine.Socket.POLLING_TIMEOUT_MS = interval;
```

I can control the polling rate.  What I'm wondering is:

- How do I know if/when the client is going to go into "poll mode" in production?
- Is it possible to force the client into "poll mode"?
- What happens if I reach the channel quota for my app?  will the /_ah/channel/ endpoint just stop working altogether?  or will it resort to polling?

-Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers:

1. The client will never go into polling mode in production. The implementation is completely different in prod.
2. See above
3. The call to create_channel() will fail and you won't be able to get any more tokens. Existing tokens (and hence channels) will work until they time out.

Hope that helps!

-Moishe